# S#arp Architecture / NHibernate with multiple databases

Tags: nhibernate, s#arp-architecture

I'm using S#arp Architecture (which uses NHibernate). I have some entities mapped to tables in one database and others mapped to a different database. Disclosure: Databases already exist so i can't do model first.

How do I configure this to work?

EDIT: Would the SchemaIs method in Fluent NHibernate be the recommended approach to map an entity to a table in a different database? I believe this is possible via NHib's xmp mapping files too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use NHibernateSession.AddConfiguration instead for additional database. The call to NHibernateSession.AddConfiguration goes immediately under NHibernateSession.Init(). An explicit session factory key will have to be defined for the second initialization.

The whole process is explained here in detail.

https://github.com/sharparchitecture/sharp-architecture/wiki?Page=FAQ

Answer (score 2):

The way I have done this is to initialise multiple NHibernateSessions in InitializeNHibernateSession within global.asax.cs using multiple nhibernate config files. I then used [Transaction("nhibernate.dbname")] (dbname being names assigned to WebSessionStorages) in the controllers against each appropriate action method.

Comment: Could you post a sample of your InitializeNHibernateSession method please? Thanks.

Comment: Here you go...

public override void Init()
{
base.Init();
webSessionStorage1 = new WebSessionStorage(this, "nhibernate.db1");
webSessionStorage2 = new WebSessionStorage(this, "nhibernate.db2");
}

...

private void InitializeNHibernateSession()
{
NHibernateSession.Init(
webSessionStorage1,
new string[] { Server.MapPath("~/bin/MyProject.Data.dll") },
Server.MapPath("~/NHibernateDB1.config"));

NHibernateSession.Init(
webSessionStorage2,
new string[] { Server.MapPath("~/bin/MyProject.Data.dll") },
Server.MapPath("~/NHibernateDB2.config"));
}

Comment: What if one controller action operates on both the database?

Comment: I have never done this, but perhaps the action could call two other methods in the controller with Transaction annotations referencing each DB?